# Email Regex with firstName.LastName limiting domain name

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
"^\w+@(email1|email2|email3|email4|email5)+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$"
```

which works to limit what domain name people can use to register. However some people have addresses like this:

```
FirstName.LastName@email1.com
```

So even though their domain name matches, they're not able to register.

Any suggestions as to how I can include an optional `"first.last"` in this Regex?

Comment: What about `....co.uk` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply checking for not `@`?

```
^[^@]+@...
```

To actually check for `.`: (if more than 1 anywhere is okay)

```
^(\w|\.)+@...
```

If you want to limit the `.` to 1:

```
^\w+(\.\w+)?@...
```

(where `...` is `(email1|email2|email3|email4|email5)+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$`)

Comment: Saved me! Another minute and my company would have broken out the pitchforks and torches.

Answer (score 3):

This regex should work for you:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-\/=?\^_`{|}~-]+@(?:email1|email2|email3|email4|email5)(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+$
```

This will cover following cases:

- abc@email1.com
- abc@email2.co.uk
- abc@email3.jp.co.uk
- first.last@email4.jp.co.uk

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/VmPw0Q3unZ

Answer (score 0):

You build a smaller regex that handles the validation of the initial part of the email before the domain.  Right now you are using `\w+` so if you are validating on JUST those two cases (word or word.word) you could change the regex to `^(\w|\w.\w)+@(email1|email2|email3|email4|email5)+?.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$`